# appending float to date frame with loop and datetime index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm calculating the long wave incident, but in my for every eight days I calculate (to be able to compare with the `MODIS` sensor!), But I can not append or concatenate in my df since the output of is is in float which makes it impossible for me to concatenate/append in one df. I would like to know if there is a way to do it by appending it to a df with the correct date, I am not finding anything in the pandas related to this.  At pandas I did not find anything similar for me to base. Here's my script:

```
#[ 1 ] 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

#[ 2 ] open
all_bands = pd.read_hdf('./MODA1_A2_Q1_v0.3.hd5')
In [3]print (all_bands)

Out [3]print (all_bands)
             band1   band2   band3   band4   band5   band6   band7     LST  
2009-01-01  0.0710  0.2047  0.0402  0.0804  0.2833  0.2799  0.1930   29.79   
2009-01-09  0.0414  0.2208  0.0190  0.0553  0.2325  0.1610  0.0703   29.85   
2009-01-17  0.0423  0.2649  0.0238  0.0650  0.2185  0.1463  0.0601   27.43   
2009-01-25  0.0588  0.3703  0.0265  0.0862  0.3132  0.2171  0.0874   25.81   
2009-02-02  0.0350  0.2798  0.0151  0.0530  0.2358  0.1456  0.0598   27.71   
2009-02-10  0.0298  0.3054  0.0142  0.0487  0.2683  0.1486  0.0545   26.23   
2009-02-18  0.0412  0.5144  0.0204  0.0790  0.4262  0.2488  0.0901   23.75   
2009-02-26  0.2153  0.4529  0.1924  0.2189  0.3900  0.2491  0.1315 -273.15   
2009-03-06  0.0408  0.4116  0.0218  0.0742  0.3368  0.1769  0.0655   24.97   
2009-03-14  0.0354  0.3081  0.0137  0.0565  0.2756  0.1353  0.0486   23.31   
2009-03-22  0.0726  0.5704  0.0367  0.1232     NaN  0.2711  0.1142   25.25   

#[ 3 ] create
all_bands['Kin'] = np.nan

# for
for dj in range(1,366,8):
    Eo = 1 + 0.033 * math.cos((2*np.pi*dj)/365)
    Kin = tal * 1367 * Eo * math.cos(z)

    together = pd.concat([all_bands.Kin, Kin], axis=1)        
#    all_bands.Kin = pd.concat(all_bands.Kin, ignore_index=False)
    print(Kin)
692.0941587661847
691.8326204874852
691.1574491223456
690.0814291052029
```

My `print` shows that mine is calculating the values correctly, but my problem is to append to my df with certain dates. Anyone have an idea how I can do it?
Thank you!

UPDATE!

I got it using:

```
dj = all_bands.index.dayofyear Eo = 1 + 0.033 * np.cos((2*np.pi*dj)/365) 
z = lat-declinacao 
all_bands['Kin'] = tal * 1367 * Eo * np.cos(np.radians(solpos.zenith))
```

Comment: Please share your `df.to_dict()` Eventually convert `datetime` to `str` first.

Comment: i got it using:
dj = all_bands.index.dayofyear
Eo = 1 + 0.033 * np.cos((2*np.pi*dj)/365)
z = lat-declinacao
all_bands['Kin'] = tal * 1367 * Eo * np.cos(np.radians(solpos.zenith))

Comment: I guess that we need `all_bands` too.